# Dispositivo real contra emulador Android Studio

Tags: android, emulador

he creado una pequeña aplicación para conocer cuáles son las dimensiones y densidades de distintos dispositivos. Compruebo que las dimensiones del emulador son más pequeñas que las del real y no comprendo por qué, ya que el emulador está creado con las mismas dimensiones del real. En el caso del Oppo no se puede crear el emulador con la densidad y dimensiones del real aún editando el archivo config.ini del AVD.

Dejo captura de pantalla de los resultados en el Bq real y emulado donde se comprueba que el emulador no usa las mismas dimensiones que el dispositivo real, y del código empleado en la aplicación de dimensiones por si me he equivocado en algo.

Necesito saber a qué atenerme porque tengo una aplicación en la que saber la altura de la pantalla es fundamental y ahora mismo no me fío de ningún emulador. Si me podéis decir algo sobre cómo corregir el fallo del emulador o cualquier otra cosa que pueda ayudarme, os quedaré muy agradecido. Saludos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código MainActivity

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texto1);
        TextView text2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texto2);
        TextView text3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texto3);
        TextView text4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texto4);
        TextView text5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texto5);
        TextView text6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texto6);
        TextView text7 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texto7);
        TextView text8 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texto8);
        TextView text9 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texto9);
        TextView text10 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texto10);
        TextView text11 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texto11);
        TextView text12 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texto12);
        TextView text13 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texto13);

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

        //tamaño en pixeles
        Point size = new Point();
        //display.getSize(size); //tamaño de pantalla en pixels.
        display.getRealSize(size); //tamaño real libre de pantalla
        float width = size.x; // pixeles libres en el ancho de pantalla
        int height = size.y;  // pixeles libres en el alto de pantalla
        String width_px = getString (R.string.texto1) + width + " px";
        String height_px =  getString (R.string.texto2) + height + " px";
        text1.setText(width_px);
        text2.setText(height_px);

        //densidades en pixels
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        int widthpixels = metrics.widthPixels; //ancho absoluto del tamaño de visualización disponible en pixels
        int heightpixels = metrics.heightPixels; //alto absoluto del tamaño de visualización disponible en pixels

        String widthabs = getString (R.string.texto3) + widthpixels + "px";
        String heightabs = getString (R.string.texto4) + heightpixels + "px";
        text3.setText(widthabs);
        text4.setText(heightabs);


        float dens = metrics.density; //densidad lógica de la pantalla
        float densDPI = metrics.densityDpi;  //densidad de la pantalla en puntos por pulgada (Dots per inch)
        String dendpi = getString (R.string.texto5) + densDPI + " (logical = " + dens + ")";
        text5.setText(dendpi);

        float denx = metrics.xdpi;  // densidad en x. Los píxeles físicos exactos por pulgada de la pantalla en la dimensión X.
        String densx = getString (R.string.texto6) + denx;
        text6.setText(densx);
        float deny = metrics.ydpi;  // densidad en y. Los píxeles físicos exactos por pulgada de la pantalla en la dimensión Y.
        String densy = getString (R.string.texto7) + deny;
        text7.setText(densy);

        float dp;
        dp = (width * 160) / densDPI;
        String densi = getString (R.string.texto8) + dp;
        text8.setText(densi);

        // Dimensiones en pulgadas

        float inchesx = width / denx;
        String widthinch = getString (R.string.texto9) + inchesx;
        text9.setText(widthinch);
        float inchesux = widthpixels / denx;
        String inchux = getString (R.string.texto10) + inchesux;
        text10.setText(inchux);

        float inchesy = height / deny; //altura real en pulgadas
        String heightinch = getString (R.string.texto11) + inchesy;
        text11.setText(heightinch);
        float inchesuy = heightpixels / deny; // altura útil libre en pulgadas
        String inchuy = getString (R.string.texto12) + inchesuy;
        text12.setText(inchuy);

        double diagonal = Math.sqrt((inchesx * inchesx) + (inchesy * inchesy));
        String diag = getString (R.string.texto13) + diagonal;
        text13.setText(diag);
        }
    }
```

Comment: El ambiente de desarrollo Android está muy fragmentado y te vas a encontrar con este tipo de cosas todo el tiempo. El emulador es una buena referencia inicial, pero siempre será sano probar en varios dispositivos reales.

Comment: Gracias por contestar Jorgesys. Me preocupa la cuestión porque no puedo tener un dispositivo físico por cada uno del mercado. Por tu respuesta deduzco que Google ofrece una herramienta que no sirve más que para entretenerte. Pregunto ¿hay alguna forma de contactar con alguien del proyecto Android Studio para buscar o que de una solución a este problema? Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Como comentas:
"ahora mismo no me fío de ningún emulador"

En realidad al usar un AVD o emulador puedes definirlo con las características de un dispositivo real pero estas serían aproximadas, incluso puedes encontrar variaciones en la densidad y tamaño como lo muestras en tu tabla.

Otro problema es que en ocasiones el emulador no genera problemas relacionados con APIs pero en el dispositivo si se generan, te lo comento por la experiencia que tuve con el OS 11.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en el caso de probar características de Hardware, hasta el día de hoy incluso probando con Android 11 lo mejor es usar un dispositivo físico.

---

Personalmente evito usar el emulador y prefiero usar dispositivos físicos para probar.